# Instantiating fstream corrupts most recently defined std::string on -O0 but not -03

Tags: c++, cmake

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const std::string string_2 = "string_2";
    const std::string string_1 = "string_1";

    std::cout << string_2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << string_1 << std::endl;
    std::fstream beep("abcd");
    std::cout << string_2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << string_1 << std::endl;
    printf("%s", string_1.c_str());
}
```

I am using CMake. When I run this with `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O0 -DNDEBUG")`, I get the following bad output:

```
string_2
string_1
string_2
╘       ±o☻
╘       ±o☻
```

But when I run it after compiling it with `-03`, the problem does not exist.

Clearly, `string_1`'s value has been changed by the instantiation of an `ifstream`.

If I change the code to define `string_2` after `string_1`, it is instead `string_2` that is changed. If I make the strings static, then no change occurs.

So what is clear to me is that the most recently-defined string which is not static is having its value corrupted when the `fstream` is instantiated.

Why could this be happening?

I am using CLion 2019.1, using a MinGW environment (mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32)

Using the bundled CMake, and MinGW's bundled g++.

Comment: Where is `#include <string>`?  Don't make the mistake of assuming things work without having that header included.  Also CLion is not a C++ compiler -- it is an IDE.  Probably you're using `gcc`.

Comment: The same problem exists whether or not I #include <string>.

I've updated the post with some environment info.

Comment: General rule of thumb is if a problem exists in debug mode but not in optimized, there's UB and debug caught it. Optimized code makes the assumption there isn't UB so things can appear to work.  For a while.

Comment: Can you clarify, what's UB?

Comment: This seems like you have an ABI mismatch between the headers you’re including and the standard library implementation you’re linking to.

Comment: UB = [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/).